# Create list IEnumerable<CustomClass> using a property of type CustomClass?

Tags: c#, list, casting, ienumerable

How can I intelligently create a `List<int>` from an `IEnumerable<CustomClass>`, if `CustomClass` has a property of type `int`, called `customProperty` which I wish to use to create my `List<int>` ?

I know I can create a `List<CustomClass>` by calling `instance.ToList<CustomClass>();`

How can I extract the property info to populate my list? What is best practice here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Linq, you can project to the property and `ToList()` the resulting `IEnumerable<int>`:

```
var ints = customClasses.Select(c => c.customProperty).ToList();
```

If you have never seen Linq extension methods before, `Select` is a common "projection" method. It takes a lambda expression, in this case an expression taking a type `CustomClass` represented as `c`, it returns whatever you want it to, in this case an `int`. As `Select` is working on a set (enumerable of something) you actually get an `IEnumerable<int>` in response, it can infer the type of `IEnumerable` based on your `Select` lambda.

If you want a delay-run `IEnumerable<int>`, simply drop the `ToList()` call.

I never like to impart opinion on best practice, but this is a clean one-liner that clearly shows intent (assuming basic understanding of Linq) and I see it all over the place.

**Linq Resources:**

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/84521/LINQ-for-the-Beginner

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19154/Understanding-LINQ-C

**Lambda Expression Resources:**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx

Alternatively, these topics are very easily searched with terms like "LINQ tutorials" or "lambda expression tutorials".

Comment: Thanks very much for this answer. Would you mind explaining what the ".Select(c => c.customProperty)." notation is doing here a little more? I have never seen notation like this before.

Comment: @Simon I've actually just updated my answer with a little run through. I'll try to fetch some learning resources too.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming C# 3.0, and hence LINQ,

```
var intList = instance.Select(cc => cc.customProperty).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is easily done using a Linq projection. With functional notation:

```
 var myEnumerable = new IEnurable<CustomClass>;
 // ... fill myEnumerable
 List<int> customProperties
   = myEnumrable.Select(item => item.customProperty).ToList();
```

The lambada expression `item => item.customProperty` projects the int, so you get a list of int. Basically, the lambda expression is equivalent of a function which receives `item` as parameter and returns `item.customProperty` as result. Something like `int foo(CustomaClass item) { return item.customProperty}`. The particularity of the lambda expression is that it's anonymous (there is no `foo`) and the return and parameter types are inferred from the context.

[Lambda Expressions (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx)

Alternative:

```
 List<int> customProperties
   = (from item in myEnumerable
      select item.customProperty).ToList();
```

In this case the projection is done directly in the `select` clause. All the LINQ query is between paretheses to allow materializing it with `ToList()`.

[Query Expression Syntax Examples: Projection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738447.aspx)

And here I leave a code fragment where you can see all the variations of a similar query:

```
    public class Thing
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal Value { get; set; }
    }

    public decimal GetValue(Thing thing)
    {
        return thing.Value;
    }

    public Thing[] Things =
        {
            new Thing { Name="Stapler", Value=20.35M},
            new Thing { Name="Eraser", Value=0.65M}
        };

    [TestMethod]
    public void GetValueListFromThing()
    {
        // query notation, direct projection
        List<decimal> valuesA 
            = (from t in Things
               select t.Value).ToList();

        // query notation, projection with method
        List<decimal> valuesB 
            = (from t in Things
               select GetValue(t)).ToList();

        // functional notation, projection with method
        List<decimal> valuesC 
            = Things.Select(t => GetValue(t)).ToList();

        // functional notation, projection with anonymous delegate
        List<decimal> valuesD 
            = Things.Select(t => { return t.Value; }).ToList();

        // functional notation, lambda expression
        List<decimal> values
            = Things.Select(t => t.Value).ToList();

    }
```